# How to access Google Earth Historical Tiled Imagery Url to other Map APIs or Cesium.js?

Tags: google-earth

Does anyone know how to access Google Earth Historical Tiled Imagery url?

Then, the users can load the xyz tiled imagery by using different map APIs such as OpenLayers 3, Leaflet, and Google Map APIs or Cesium.js?

I assume that I can make a request of the tiled imagery by the url similar as following: http://mt{1-3}.google.com/vt/lyrs=p&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&time=yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm

or

http://mt{1-3}.google.com/vt/lyrs=p&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&begin=yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm&end=yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm

Did anyone try to access Google Earth historical imagery tiles? or it's no way to access it by sending url requests?

Comment: Please use FireFox to browse following Google Earth API based tool to search historical imagery. http://www.gearthblog.com/js/FindByDate.html

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, this is not [is no longer] possible. For a workaround using downloaded Google Earth Imagery, see [Uploading older Google Earth Historical Imagery into QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360019/uploading-older-google-earth-historical-imagery-into-qgis)

Alternatively, you can browse ESRI/Arcgis historical imagery at https://livingatlas.arcgis.com/wayback and then access it via WMT/WMTS at https://wayback.maptiles.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

Comment: this is awesome! Thanks @Houska!